# Is it possible to apply Matlab optmization toolbox on excel?

Tags: excel, matlab

I have an excel file, with different worksheets and in this file everything is connected and I also have some computations for almost all values (formulas) and I want to do a multi-objective optimization to this work. Since matlab solves multi-objective optimization problems I would like to use it. So I want to know if it is possible to use matlab optimization toolbox as and add-in for excel, so I won't have to do everything again on matlab.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can create a script in Matlab that loads the data from an excel file, performs the optimization and writes the new data in excel format. I don't know if that's what you want to achieve.

Comment: I think you are looking for https://uk.mathworks.com/products/excellink/ but you will have to pay for it I think...

Comment: @BlackAdder My objective functions are computed by a formula referencing values from other woorksheets

Comment: @GameOfThrows I'm gonna try, thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Excel Link](http://www.mathworks.com/products/excellink/) most likely isn't going to be of any use here.  It's good when you want to use Excel as a front-end, and then push/pull data to/from MATLAB, and for calling MATLAB functions from Excel.  But it isn't going to allow you to use the spreadsheet as a cost function within a call to an optimization function, with the cells updating as the optimization progresses (which is what it sounds as if you are trying to do).

You could try setting up an optimization in MATLAB where the cost function that you write uses [actxserver](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/actxserver.html) to manipulate your spreadsheet.  However, that's not going to be trivial to achieve, and you may find that the speed (or lack thereof) of accessing the spreadsheet is prohibitive.

You'll most likely find that the above is harder than rewriting the cost function in m-code (which you're obviously trying to avoid).

Alternatively if you really can't move out of Excel then you should look at using an Excel optimization package.  *Solver* in the first instance (although it is very light weight), or one of the many other optimization add-ins available.

Comment: The solver doesn't allow multi-objective . The problem is that my file has a lot of computations, it would take a lot of time to do everything in matlab. And I don't know multi-objective softwares that are that much complex